# Soving Killing equation for AdS3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the Killing equations$(\nabla_{\mu}X_{\nu}+\nabla_{\nu}X_{\mu}=0)$ for the AdS3 metric
$$ds^2=\frac{-dt^2+dx^2+dz^2}{z^2}$$

The Killing equation gives me
$$1)~~\partial_tX_{t}+{X_z\over z}=0,~2)~~\partial_xX_{x}-{X_z\over z}=0,~~3)~~\partial_zX_{z}+{X_z\over z}=0\\4)~~\partial_xX_{t}+\partial_tX_{x}=0,~5)~~\partial_zX_{t}+\partial_tX_{z}+{2X_t\over z}=0,~6)~~\partial_zX_{x}+\partial_xX_{z}+{2X_x\over z}=0$$

Equation 3) gives me $X_z={f(x,t)\over z}$ Plugging this in 1) and 2) gives
$$X_{t}=-{1\over z^2}\int f(x,t)dt+K_1(x,z),~~X_{x}={1\over z^2}\int  f(x,t)dx+K_2(t,z)$$
substituting this in 5) and 6) gives
$$z\partial_zK_1(x,z)+2K_1(x,z)=-\partial_tf(x,t),~~z\partial_zK_2(t,z)+2K_1(t,z)=-\partial_xf(x,t)$$ . Solving for $K_1$ and $K_2$ gives
$$K_1(x,z)=-{1\over 2}\partial_t f(x,t)+{g(x)\over z^2},~~K_2(t,z)=-{1\over 2}\partial_x f(x,t)+{h(t)\over z^2}$$. Now using this and the expression for $X_t,X_x$ in 4) we get
$${1\over z^2}\left(\int \partial_t f(x,t)dx-\int \partial_x f(x,t)dt+{dg(x)\over dx}+{dh(t)\over dt}\right)-\partial_t\partial_x f(x,t)=0$$
As suggested this is of the form $A(x,t)+{B(x,t)\over z^2}=0\rightarrow A(x,t)=0,~B(x,t)=0$. Using this we get
$$\partial_t\partial_x f(x,t)=0\\
\rightarrow f(x,t)=a(t)+b(x)$$
Plugging this in the second condition gives
$$x{da(t)\over dt}+c_1-t{db(x)\over dx}-c_2+{dg(x)\over dx}+{dh(t)\over dt}=0$$
I am puzzled how to seperate this equation to obtain g & h in terms of a & b.

Comment: As for $z\partial_zK_1+2K_1=\cdots$, you may use $\partial_z\left(z^2K_1\right)=z\left(z\partial_zK_1+2K_1\right)$. This would give you $K_1$. Then you may obtain $K_2$. Finally, Eq.(4) would give you constraint(s) on $f$ and $K_1$.

Comment: @hypernova: Thanks for your comment I have updated my post. Still, I          am stuck with the final constraint equation.

Comment: (1) I suggest that you use definite integrals instead of indefinite ones, because, for example, $\int f(x,t){\rm d}t$ could include some "constant" terms that depends solely on $z$. (2) As per your last result, it is of the form $A(x,t)+B(x,t)/z^2=0$. Therefore, it is a must that $A(x,t)=0$ and $B(x,t)=0$.

Comment: @hypernova: I am looking for a general solution so I don't want to impose any condition on X. I have updated the post according to your second suggestion.